# How to create global connection?

Tags: php

I want create a global connection, so in the entire script I can access to a single object. Actually I made this class:

```
<?php

class Database {

private static $db;
private $connection;

private function __construct($conn) {
    $this->connection = $conn;   
    $this->init();
}

private function init(){
     // here the connection is going to execute
     $host = $this->_connection['host'];
     //etc...
}

function __destruct() {
    $this->connection->close();
}

public static function getConnection($conn) {
    if (self::$db == null) {
        self::$db = new Database($conn);
    }
    return self::$db->connection;
}
}

?>
```

I pass the details of connection like this: `$db = Database::getConnection($connection);` Now `$connection` contains an array with the credentials access. Here no problem all working good. The main problem is that `$db = Database::getConnection($connection);` is called only when the index create the instance of the connection. My goal is call the `$connection` object in any models or controller, example:

```
class Model
{

  function __construct()
  {
       $this->db = Database::getConnection();
  }

}
```

how you can see I can't pass the connection parameter 'cause I want just use the connection previously established by the index.php call. How I can access to this connection without pass parameter?

Comment: A solution would be to use a dependency injection container or service locator. They would be used to get the DB object without you have to keep suppling the username and password. A good example of a DI is here https://packagist.org/packages/pimple/pimple

Comment: The connection is different infact I read the connection credentials in a by a token

Comment: In that case you could create a unique service for each different connection with a service locator. That way you could have many different connections. You just have to load them using the method for getting the services. There are many packages on packagist that will provide you this functionality. So go check there first to see if you can find any that fit your needs

Comment: I want do it in my class no other services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to both make the `$conn` parameter optional and make sure it is passed on the first call:

```
public static function getConnection($conn=null) {
    if (self::$db == null) {
        if ($conn === null) {
            throw new Exception('Can not initialize the database');
        }
        self::$db = new Database($conn);
    }
    return self::$db->connection;
}
```

Then you need to call the `getConnection` somewhere during the application start and pass the configuration to it.

After that you can use it without parameters.

If, by mistake, you don't configure the database, you'll have a clear error.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
public static function getConnection($conn = null) {
    if (self::$db != null) {
        return self::$db->connection;
    }
    //maybe add some validation here to ensure that the $conn value has been set
    self::$db = new Database($conn);

    return self::$db->connection;
}
```

or this works as well although it will throw an error if you don't set the $conn on the first call.

```
public static function getConnection($conn = null) {
    if (self::$db == null && $conn) {
        self::$db = new Database($conn);
    }

    return self::$db->connection;
}
```

It changes your logic a bit but should now work as you expect it to.

If the $conn is not supplied then it wont throw an error.